Proof verification: If $(b_n)$ is a bounded (real) sequence with exactly one limit point $b$, then it is convergent.
My proof is the following: As $(b_n)$ is bounded, there is a $C>0$ such that $|b_n|\leq C$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$. Let $\epsilon > 0$. We aim to show: for nearly all $n\in \mathbb N$ we have $b_n\in N_\epsilon (b)$, where $N_\epsilon(b)$ is the $\epsilon$-neighbourhood of our limit point $b$. Assume for a contradiction that this is not the case, that is there are infinitely many $b_n$ in the set $A= [-C, C]\setminus N_\epsilon(b)$. Define $(b_{n_k})$ to be the subsequence of $(b_n)$ who's domain is the set $A$ (is this step ok?). Then this subsequence is also bounded and by Bolzano-Weierstraß it has a limit point. This is a contradiction.

Just curious…why is it necessary we have a bounded sequence? Is not the statement true regardless of whether the sequence is bounded? (Limit points are by definition $\in\mathbb{R}$ in this context.)

@JAG131 It depends on whether you count $\pm \infty$ as possible limit points. If the definitions are set up such that limit points have to be finite, then a sequence like $(0,1,0,2,0,3,0,\dots)$ will have a single limit point but won't converge.

@BrunoB Okay I see what you’re saying now. Got it! I forget that you can include +/- infty when discussing limit points.

@OP, this looks fine. The step you are unsure about is ok. Simply put, any infinite collection of elements contains a sequence, so you can define ${b_{n_k}}$.

Looking at your proof, it reads a little misguided. What is the definition for limit points in this chosen context? Broadly, it can be written symbolically as: For all nhbds around $b$ (we’ll denote $N(b)$), there exists $M>0$ such that $b_n\in N(b)$ for all $n>M$. This definition is different than the one which you provide, since a limit point at infinity does not have a well-defined $\epsilon$-nhbd. But if you’re allowed to assume that we’re dealing with $\epsilon$ nhbds, then the set up is okay (though it would be better to explicitly restate the definition of LP instead of what you have).

And also, the term “domain” should probably be replaced with “range”. But other than that, it looks pretty solid.

Your proof is correct if $N_\varepsilon(b)$ is supposed to be the open interval $(b-\varepsilon, b+\varepsilon)$ or some other open neighbourhood since that makes $A$ compact rather than just bounded. Details-wise depending on how strict you really need to be, you may have to very briefly argue that the new limit point is different from the old one, but in all cases it's pretty much perfectly fine as is for me.
$(b_{n_k})_k$ is not unique so you should say "a subsequence in $A$" rather than "the subsequence in $A$", and since sequences are technically functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to whatever space the values lie, I believe it would be more correct to say that "their range is in $A$" rather than "their domain". But these are just nitpicks which don't affect the validity of your proof, so no worries there.
